# newbie in bash scripting assistance please

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I run bash scripts from time to time on my servers, I am trying to write a script that monitors log folders and compress log files if folder exceeds defined capacity. I know there are better ways of doing what I am currently trying to do, your suggestions are more than welcome. The script below is throwing an error "unexpected end of file" .Below is my script.

```
dir_base=$1   
size_ok=5000000  
cd $dir_base  
curr_size=du -s -D | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/%//g' zipname=archivedate +%Y%m%d

if (( $curr_size > $size_ok ))
then
    echo "Compressing and archiving files, Logs folder has grown above 5G"
    echo "oldest to newest selected."
    targfiles=( `ls -1rt` )
    echo "rocess files."
    for tfile in ${targfiles[@]}
    do
        let `du -s -D | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/%//g' | tail -1`
        if [ $curr_size -lt $size_ok ];
        then
            echo "$size_ok has been reached. Stopping processes"
            break
        else  if [ $curr_size -gt $size_ok ];
        then
            zip -r $zipname $tfile
            rm -f $tfile
            echo "Added ' $tfile ' to archive'date +%Y%m%d`'.zip and removed"
        else [ $curr_size -le $size_ok ];
            echo "files in $dir_base are less than 5G, not archiving"
        fi
```

Comment: pls format your code properly again.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). Here is an [example](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/117) of putting it to use.

Answer (score 0):

With what you give us, you lack a "done" to end the for loop and a "fi" to end the main if. Please reformat your code and You will get more precise answers ...

EDIT :

Looking at your reformatted script, it is as said : The "unexpected end of file" comes from the fact you have not closed your "for" loop neither your "if"

As it seems that you mimick the logrotate behaviour, check it as suggested by @Hank...

my2c

Answer (score 0):

My `du -s -D` does not show `%` sign. So you can just do.

```
curr_size=$(du -s -D)
set -- $curr_size
curr_size=$1
```

saves you a few overheads instead of `du -s -D | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/%//g`.

If it does show `%` sign, you can get rid of it like this
`du -s -D | awk '{print $1+0}'`. No need to use `sed`.

Use `$()` syntax instead of backticks whenever possible

For `targfiles=(`ls -1rt`)` , you can omit the `-1`. So it can be
`targfiles=( $(ls -rt) )`

Use quotes around your variables whenever possible. eg "$zipname" , "$tfile"